# Alternatives to SchemaSpy

Tags: maven, jenkins, schemacrawler, schemaspy

I am looking for a open source tool that can be used to generate ER diagram.  Currently, this is done using SchemaSpy.  Maven scripts are invoked during jenkins build to generate these data model diagrams.  I have tried POCs using SchemaCrawler as well.  However, the results are not much satisfactory.  Would appreciate if I can get pointers to alternative tools that can be used along with the same setup (maven and jenkins).

Comment: btw, what is wrong with schemaspy + graphviz?

Comment: The connecting arrows are way too curved and the overall look and feel of the summary diagram can be better

Comment: There is the database design tool with [er diagram in oracle](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/oracle/studio/oracle-database-diagram.html) building functionality in dbForge Studio for Oracle.

Answer (score 8):

If you would like to find out good alternatives to SchemaSpy try to use and test this tools:

- [SchemaCrawler](https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler)
- [Red-Gate SQL Doc](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-doc/)  (not FOSS)
- [Dataedo](https://dataedo.com/) (not FOSS)
- [SchemaSpy 6.0](http://schemaspy.org/)

Each of them has different advantages and disadvantages SchemaCawler is also open source java based and free. SchemaSpy 6.0 this is new version of SchemaSpy that has better look and feel plus fix some major issue.

Dataedo is very interesting tool that has also possibility to generate documentation to pdf, html. With Dataedo you can write comments of tables and columns and after apply them on your database. As I remember on supplier page you can find also free version.

The last solution that I want to recommend is Red-Gate SQL Doc. This is also generate nice looking documentation and has many options. But as usually this solution is not free you need pay to use it.